# CSV not opening with delimiter ; but opening with delimiter , using genfromtxt

Tags: python, numpy, csv, genfromtxt

```
data = genfromtxt('C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\ML\\melb_data.csv',dtype = None,delimiter = ',')
```

The csv file opens and I can use it as a numpy array when I specify delimiter to be ,

```
data2 = genfromtxt('C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\ML\\melb_data.csv',dtype = None,delimiter = ';')
```

But if delimiter is ; it does not open

This error comes:

```
ipython-input-97-952ac6f6baeb>:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Reading unicode strings without specifying the encoding argument is deprecated. Set the encoding, use None for the system default.
  data2 = genfromtxt('C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\ML\\melb_data.csv',dtype = None,delimiter = ';')
```

Comment: Maybe the semicolon is just the wrong delimiter for the file? The error is actually only a warning about unspecified encoding.

Comment: Try adding a `encoding=None` parameter to your `genfromtxt` call.  But regardless, the choice of delimiter has to match the file.  We can't help without seeing a sample.